# Django template - render object with specific attribute

Tags: python, django-models, django-templates

I want my template to render object with specific attribute (products with specific category).
I am trying following code but it doesn't work.
May you please suggest how to write it correctly?

Template that I am trying make to work:

```
{% for instance in object_list %}
{% if instance.category == 'Statues' %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

my **models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    categoryname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    #To make in name, not objXXX
    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoryname

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/photos', default='http://placehold.it/700x400')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    #To make in name, not objXXX
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the field on the object;

```html
{% for instance in object_list %}
    {% if instance.category.categoryname == 'Statues' %}
        {{ instance }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It won't work as a comparison against the string representation of the object.